# API para filtrar o eliminar malas palabras

Tags: python, filtro

Quisiera saber, si alguno de ustedes conoce alguna API que permita filtrar o eliminar malas palabras.

Por ejemplo cuando un usuario quiera enviar un comentario o mensaje y este contenga malas palabras no le permita postear o enviar dicho mensaje.

La solución más pronta que he pensado es crear como especie de diccionario, almacenar ciertas palabras y que cuando un usuario intente enviar un comentario con groserias primero verifique si cada una de las palabras están en una "black list" se podría decir.

Si pudieran ayudarme, se los agradezco

Comment: Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta es basada en opiniones, por lo tanto, aquí te dejo la mía: No es prudente *censurar* al usuario, eso te convierte en un villano, lo prudente es tener un sistema para que se pueda reportar el uso indebido y puedas atacar el problema recibiendo y solventando los reportes. Por ejemplo, tal como funciona [es.so]. Si yo escribo una grosería o dejo un comentario que cause ofensa o molestias, los otros usuarios pueden reportar mi comentario y el mismo será eliminado o me llamarán la atención por ello.

Comment: Incluso, si mi comportamiento es reincidente, se me puede suspender la cuenta. Esa tal vez es una forma un poco más adecuada de evitar el abuso o el mal uso del lenguaje. Pero suprimir de entrada, sólo hará que se inventen formas diferentes de escribir groserías, usando mil y una forma que no sea detectable por tu algoritmo, dando paso a que lo que intentas lograr no sea posible. En cambio, usando la moderación de tu sitio, seguro que el resultado será mejor. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dejaré un algoritmo solucion en python, si necesitas en otro lenguaje me comentás, osea te recomiendo que uses una Funcion, no una api, ya que es un problema simple:

1. Podes denegar toda la frase si encuentras alguna mala palabra

   ```
    def esMala(palabra):
      malasPalabras = ["unaMalaPalabra", "otraMalaPalabra"]
      return palabra in malasPalabras


    def esBuenaFrase(frase):
      esBuenaFrase = True

      listaDePalabras = frase.split() # separa por espacios en palabras
      for unaPalabra in listaDePalabras:
        if esMala(unaPalabra):
          esBuenaFrase = False
          break

      return esBuenaFrase
   ```

Luego en tu programa pones:

```
      frase = input()
      if (esBuenaFrase(frase)):
        #Go ON
      else:
        print("Por Favor Elimine las malas palabras y reescriba el mensaje")
```

Por otro lado, si quieres reemplazar cada malapalabra con asteriscos debes recorrer cada palabra y reemplazar la variable frase. Finalmente volver a separar todo con espacios

```
def filtrarPalabras(frase):
  listaDePalabras = frase.split() # separa por espacios en palabras
  for i in range (len(listaDePalabras)):
    if esMala(listaDePalabras[i]):
      listaDePalabras[i] = ****
```

Este ultimo lo dejo incompleto porque es mas complejo espero te sirva saludos

Comment: Observación si bien el aporte es interesante lo ideal es no responder a preguntas basadas en opiniones pues terminan cerradas

Comment: excelente, no responder a preguntas tan abiertas. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. De momento tu ejemplo me funcionó.